# How to reasign object with `this` in Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, button, this

I have 2 variables inside an Angular component/class `FilterComponent` that point to an object. The first one (`localStorage`) stores the results of the current filtering choices that the user makes and is connected with toogle buttons with `[(ngValue)]`. The second one (`globalStorage`) gets the results of filtering choices that the user made earlier within other components (if you for example click on `fruit` on home page,globalStorage.food gets updated, but not the `localStorage` within `FilterComponent`). I have a method that should assign gloablStorage to localStorage when the user open the filter that looks like this:

```
openFilter() {
  this.localStorage = this.globalStorage; //this line is responsible for strange behaviour
  ...
}
```

This works exactly like it should, but only after the `apply` button on filter (within FilterComponent) is clicked, which is responsible for sending the contents of localStorage to globalStorage (via next/behaviourSubject).

For some mysterious reason, before that happens, the values of toggleButtons get assign to globalStorage as well as to localStorage (although they are connected only to localStorage). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to create stackblitz for that

Comment: Not at the moment, but I can do it tomorrow!

Comment: FYI: I would recommend renaming your properties to reflect how you're using them and avoid using words commonly used to mean something else in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `this.localStorage = this.globalStorage;` and these 2 variables are objects, it means this.localStorage now point/refer to this.globalStorage, so from now on this 2 variable will refer to 1 place.

If you just want to copy data inside it you should do a copy instead of simple assign by using either Object.assign(shallow copy) or this.local = {...this.global} for loop deep copy

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. The solution (that's good enough for now) was to reassign each property:

```
this.localStorage.property1 = this.localStorage.property1;
this.localStorage.property2 = this.localStorage.property2;
```